# How to get complete stacktrace from a stripped binary using perf?

Tags: linux, profiling, stack-trace, debug-symbols, perf

I am trying to profile a process written for en embedded linux system. It is for a product we are developing. Name of the process is set to "dummy" for confidentiality reasons. It was suggested to me to use perf to profile dummy. So i tried bunch of different perf commands in order to get idea of what internal functions defined within dummy are in hot zone and how well we are calling stuff into libc and libglib. Here is an example of perf top when dummy was running at 99% CPU. It is run as "perf top -G -p "

```
+  13.75%  libc-2.18.so             [.] 0x000547a2                                                                         
+   7.52%  [kernel]                 [k] __do_softirq                                                                       
+   6.97%  libglib-2.0.so.0.3600.4  [.] 0x00089d60                                                                         
+   2.87%  libpthread-2.18.so       [.] 0x000085c4                                                                         
+   2.71%  libpthread-2.18.so       [.] pthread_mutex_lock                                                                 
+   2.62%  libc-2.18.so             [.] malloc                                                                             
+   2.51%  [kernel]                 [k] vector_swi                                                                         
+   1.87%  [kernel]                 [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore                                                        
+   1.49%  [kernel]                 [k] __getnstimeofday                                                                   
+   1.45%  dummy                    [.] chksum_crc32_int                                                                   
+   1.34%  [kernel]                 [k] fget_light                                                                         
+   1.29%  [kernel]                 [k] _raw_spin_unlock_bh                                                                
+   1.28%  [kernel]                 [k] memcpy                                                                             
+   1.24%  [adkNetD]                [k] adk_netd_clean_nca_queue         
.
.
.
```

I don't understand the output fully, even though I have some ideas. So here are my questions.

1. What does last column signify? Isn't it the functions being called within the binary or library that is listed on left?
2. Then does that mean 0x000547a2 in 1st row is a symbol/function defined in process libc?
3. Since all libraries and binaries on the target product are stripped, I can understand the perf can't show a resolved stacktrace with real function names. But I searched for 0x000547a2 in debug symbol file built separately for libc (was delivered together with libc), but I couldn't find the symbol. The closest I could find was

`00054750 t _int_malloc`

4. Is there a way I can specify the debug symbol files that I have to perf?